# Trying to loop through a webpage to scrape all football players names, but only getting the first one?

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to scrape all the names of the players on Alabama's football roster, found here: https://rolltide.com/roster.aspx?roster=226&path=football

I'm able to get the first players name, but it stops after him and doesn't get any other players name.

Here is my code:

```py
DesiredRoster = (URLEntry.get())

driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get(DesiredRoster)

#Player Name

Name = driver.find_element_by_class_name('sidearm-roster-player-name')
PlayerName = Name.find_element_by_tag_name('a').text
print(PlayerName)
```

How would I loop through this webpage to get all names?

```py
numbers = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('sidearm-roster-player-jersey-number')
print(numbers.text)
```

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'

Weirdly enough it will print the first players number if I change `elements` to `element`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a `driver` method which only returns a single value `find_element_by_class_name`, switch to `find_elements_by_class_name` to get a list then iterate through the list:

```
names = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('sidearm-roster-player-name')
for name in names:
    player_name = name.find_element_by_tag_name('a').text
    print(player_name)
```

Comment: This works perfectly. I'm having issues scraping the players numbers now though using this same strategy. Possibly because it is a value and not text? Error is 'list object has no attribute text'

Comment: It sounds like the issue is that whatever find function you're calling is returning a list, then you're trying to get the `text` attribute for that list, which it doesn't have, hence the error.  Not sure about the contents of the list, maybe you need to iterate over the values in the list and check that text?  Without seeing the function you're using it's hard to say.

Answer (score 2):

In my case at least an `User-Agent` header was required and I could then use `requests`. You can then gather the parent nodes with a css class selector and then loop those parents and extract required info into a dataframe; again, using faster and short css selectors. As mentioned, the key is to gather all parent nodes in this case by using `select`. This has less overhead than selenium.

---

**Py:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import pandas as pd

r = requests.get('https://rolltide.com/roster.aspx?roster=226&path=football', headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
results = {}

for num, p in enumerate(soup.select('.sidearm-roster-player')):
    results[num] = {'position': p.select_one('.sidearm-roster-player-position >span:first-child').text.strip()
           ,'height': p.select_one('.sidearm-roster-player-height').text
           ,'weight': p.select_one('.sidearm-roster-player-weight').text
           ,'number': p.select_one('.sidearm-roster-player-jersey-number').text
           ,'name': p.select_one('.sidearm-roster-player-name a').text
           ,'year': p.select_one('.sidearm-roster-player-academic-year').text
           ,'hometown': p.select_one('.sidearm-roster-player-hometown').text
           ,'highschool': p.select_one('.sidearm-roster-player-highschool').text
          }
df = pd.DataFrame(results.values(), columns = ['position','height','weight','number','name','year','hometown','highschool'])
print(df)
```

---

**R:**

`purrr` is used to handle loop over parent nodes to write to df. `str_squish` from `stringr` is used to tidy up output of one child node in loop. `httr` is used to provide header.

```
library(httr)
library(purrr)
library(rvest)
library(stringr)

headers = c('User-Agent' = 'Mozilla/5.0')
pg <- content(httr::GET(url = 'https://rolltide.com/roster.aspx?roster=226&path=football', httr::add_headers(.headers=headers)))

df <- map_df(pg%>%html_nodes('.sidearm-roster-player'), function(item) {

     data.frame(position = str_squish(item%>%html_node('.sidearm-roster-player-position >span:first-child')%>%html_text()),
                height = item%>%html_node('.sidearm-roster-player-height')%>%html_text(),
                weight = item%>%html_node('.sidearm-roster-player-weight')%>%html_text(),
                number = item%>%html_node('.sidearm-roster-player-jersey-number')%>%html_text(),
                name = item%>%html_node('.sidearm-roster-player-name a')%>%html_text(),
                year = item%>%html_node('.sidearm-roster-player-academic-year')%>%html_text(),
                hometown = item%>%html_node('.sidearm-roster-player-hometown')%>%html_text(),
                highschool = item%>%html_node('.sidearm-roster-player-highschool')%>%html_text(),
                stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
     })

View(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wanting to use R (`rvest`), here is the code that collects the roster data into a data frame:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
library(rvest)

url <- "https://rolltide.com/roster.aspx?roster=226&path=football"
page <- url %>% read_html()

position <- list()
height <- list()
weight <- list()
number <- list()
name <- list()
yr <- list()
hometown <- list()
high.school <- list()

for (i in seq(1,250)) {
    position[[i]] <- page %>% html_nodes(xpath=paste0('//*[@id="main-content"]/article/div[4]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/section/ul/li[',i,']/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/span[1]/text()')) %>% xml_text %>% str_trim
    height[[i]] <- page %>% html_nodes(xpath=paste0('//*[@id="main-content"]/article/div[4]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/section/ul/li[',i,']/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/span[2]')) %>% xml_text
    weight[[i]] <- page %>% html_nodes(xpath=paste0('//*[@id="main-content"]/article/div[4]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/section/ul/li[',i,']/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/span[3]/text()')) %>% xml_text
    number[[i]] <- page %>% html_nodes(xpath=paste0('//*[@id="main-content"]/article/div[4]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/section/ul/li[',i,']/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/span/span')) %>% xml_text
    name[[i]] <- page %>% html_nodes(xpath=paste0('//*[@id="main-content"]/article/div[4]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/section/ul/li[',i,']/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/p/a')) %>% xml_text
    yr[[i]] <- page %>% html_nodes(xpath=paste0('//*[@id="main-content"]/article/div[4]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/section/ul/li[',i,']/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/span[1]')) %>% xml_text
    hometown[[i]] <- page %>% html_nodes(xpath=paste0('//*[@id="main-content"]/article/div[4]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/section/ul/li[',i,']/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/span[2]/text()')) %>% xml_text
    high.school[[i]] <- page %>% html_nodes(xpath=paste0('//*[@id="main-content"]/article/div[4]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/section/ul/li[',i,']/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/span[3]/text()')) %>% xml_text
}

position    %<>% tibble %>% unnest
height      %<>% tibble %>% unnest
weight      %<>% tibble %>% unnest
number      %<>% tibble %>% unnest
name        %<>% tibble %>% unnest
yr          %<>% tibble %>% unnest
hometown    %<>% tibble %>% unnest
high.school %<>% tibble %>% unnest

final <- bind_cols(position,height,weight,number,name,yr,hometown,high.school)
names(final) <- c("position","height","weight","number","name","yr","hometown","high.school")
```

The trick is to select the Xpath instead of the CSS selector and use `xpath=` in the `html_nodes()` call.

It's obviously a bit uglier, but it doesn't require Selenium or other heavy setups.

**EDIT**: You should look at QHarr's answer above for more streamlined code.

Comment: This is a very fragile strategy and slow due to the long xpaths.  You would be better choosing appropriate short css selectors.

Comment: @QHarr I agree! If you can figure out how to get the info using CSS selectors for this page, I would love to see it. I think the ASPX structure of the page renders the CSS selectors useless.

Comment: added an answer using css. If I missed something let me know. I have only done page at link as shown.

Comment: you are awesome, thanks for posting! I didn't know how about the `User-Agent` header; that will be super useful for me.